# Javascript redirect behaving differently than manually entring URL

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm trying to write a LibreJS compatibility web extension for a website. The intended browser is Icecat version 52+.

A form is broken on this website because it has a proprietary `onSubmit` script.

When I set the `onSubmit` of the form to my extension's JavaScript and submit the form, it responds with a URL.

When entered manually by copying and pasting this URL into the URL bar it redirects to the correct page.

However, when I get the exact same URL in Javascript and redirect it like this, the webpage behaves differently and gives an error page saying it thinks it's a crawler.

I have tried every other method for redirecting I could find on Stack Overflow like setting `document.location.href`, `window.location.href`, `window.location.replace(redirect)`)

My question is how do I fix this? Code:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('POST', url, true);
http.onload = function (){
    console.log("URL in response to post:");            
    var redirect = // verified this is the correct URL
    location.href = redirect; // website gives an error page:
    //Error! No saved objectValues at all -- crawler? bad link? filter?
    return;

};
http.send(form_data);
```

Comment: Can you check what Referrer IceCat sends? I'm guessing that the site expect there to be no referrer, or for it to NOT be from the current site, but IceCat is sending a referrer header it doesn't like. Also, just because I'm curious, what is a "proprietary  onSubmit script" in this context?

Comment: A proprietary onSubmit script is the form validation script not being released under a free software license. 

I know it sounds stupid to block a script that works, but IceCat isn't really about convenience. It's for those who really hate it when their browser works against their interests in any way.  

Will get back in the next hour or so after I check the referer...

Comment: @Hamish I just tried to figure out the refferer of my requests but it quickly became unmanagable because I really don't understand how this website I'm making this addon for works. Remember it works correctly if you just copy and paste the URL into the URL bar so that's all I'm trying to do.